# How do you split a string if you know the start and stop point but not the middle in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, split

I'm attempting to remove a section of a string that can change at anytime. This makes it difficult to split the string to remove said section. There is a point before and after the section to remove that is constant.

Here is the only way I can think of to accurately show an example (please ignore the fact that it is html):

```
string text = 
"<ul>
<li>keep this text</li>
<li class=Known  unknown text  </li>
<li>keep this text</li>
</ul>";  

string [] splitPerams = {"","<li class=Known (im guessing a regex here) 
</li>"}

string [] results = 
text.Split(splitPerams,System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

output:

```
"<ul>
<li>keep this text</li>

<li>keep this text</li>
</ul>";
```

I know there are a lot of similar questions regarding this subject, but all of them are in different languages, and I cant figure out how to implement the logic in c#.

EDIT:I guess I'm not allowed to delete this so I will do my best to just reword it completely for better understanding.

Comment: You shouldn't be using string manipulation to handle HTML, there are dedicated libraries for this: [HtmlAgilityPack](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack) and [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) are the two most popular

Comment: @maccettura The project I'm working on requires this. However, this question refers to how to split a string. The contents of the string should have nothing to do with this. If it is more helpfull I will give a different string example.

Comment: Well if your _actual real life input_ is HTML, then use the libraries like I said.  If you want to do this without using a library then you are free to look at how the libraries function since they are open source.

Comment: Your new example makes even less sense.  If you just want the first `x` number of digits just use `Substring()`

Comment: This isn't so much a split as a truncation.  Can't you just use substring? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I dont know the number of characters before the section I'm trying to remove or yes substring() would work.

Comment: Ok so a combination of indexOf and substring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: I posted an answer using them together.

Comment: I guess I'm not allowed to delete this post so I redid it to hopefully make more sense. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @Sentius this was solved for you by my very first comment.  Unless you want to write your own HTML parsing library, **just use an already existing one**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by some chance this helps someone, here is the way to remove/pull an unknown section of text from a string when you know the part before and after the unknown section.

```
string originalText = "Hi my name is Mr. Smith from the USA.";

string[] topPull = { "", "Mr." };
string[] bottomPull = { "from", "" };
string result;

string[] topPage = originalText.Split(topPull,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] bottomPage = 
originalText.Split(bottomPull,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


//topPage[0] gives all text above topPull, but not topPull it's self
//bottomPull[1] gives all text below bottomPull, but not bottomPull it's self
//now that we have grabbed all the text above and below our known sections we need to 
//add in the known sections themselves, ie topPull and bottomPull

result = topPage[0] + topPull[1] + " " + bottomPull[0] + bottomPage[1];
```

output: "Hi my name is Mr. from the USA."

---

If you want to keep only the middle text you can do it this way

```
string originalText = "Hi my name is Mr. Smith from the USA.";

string[] topPull = { "", "Mr." };
string[] bottomPull = { "from", "" };
string result;

string[] topPage = originalText.Split(topPull,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] bottomPage = 
topPage[1].Split(bottomPull,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
result = bottomPage[0];
```

output: " Smith ";

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need isn't a split so much as the front end of a string so using `substring` should do it.  Since you know what characters the removing section starts with, using `indexOf` will be useful.

```
var str = "Hi My name is Mr. ???? from the usa.";
var newStr = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf("Mr."));
```

Play around with that to get the exact length you want.

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Isn't he trying to remove what the result of newStr would be? In that case you could use Regex.Replace on str, now that you know the unknown text (in newStr).

Comment: In one of the iterations of the many edits, he gave what I have as `str` and his desired result was `"Hi My name is"`.  in my snippet that is what would be held in `newStr` (plus or minus a white space character depending on his exact requirement).

Comment: This would have worked if I only needed the text before Mr. which was bad wording on my part, hence all the edits. Sorry.